# How do you use GitHub's primer and octicons?

Tags: html, css, github, sass

I'm trying to use GitHub's [primer](https://github.com/primer/primer) and [octicons](https://github.com/primer/octicons). After using `npm` to install both I started using the css classes defined by GitHub by including the `build.css` file in my html document. How would I point the project towards all the svg icons that `octicons` gives me?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello Primer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/primer-css/build/build.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                <span class="input-group-button">
          <button class="btn">
            <span class="octicon octicon-clippy"></span>
                </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[edit]** short answer: include `node_modules/octicons/build/font/octicons.css`

This works, without svg icons. If you want to use the svg icons, you should probably include the images using `<img>` tags. However, using a font makes this a lot easier.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Primer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/primer-css/build/build.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/octicons/build/font/octicons.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <span class="input-group-button">
                <button class="btn">
                    <span class="octicon octicon-clippy"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

## Edit

And if you really feel the need for it, here is an version using `svg`'s:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Primer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/primer-css/build/build.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/octicons/build/octicons.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <span class="input-group-button">
                <button class="btn">
                    <span class="octicon octicon-clippy"></span>
                    <img src="node_modules/octicons/lib/svg/clippy.svg"></img>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why did you include the `src: url('node_modulles/octicons/build/font/octicons.woff') format('woff')` lines? it seems like `node_modules` is misspelled, I commented it out and everything still worked, so are those lines not required?

Comment: Good catch. They are also included in `octicons/build/font/octicons.css` so are not needed. I guess I included them because I first used the wrong css file.

Comment: As of this writing, `npm install octicons` does not include a `font` directory or an `octicons.css` file. Not sure what's up with that.

Comment: @shacker They switched to building route so they will not provide the fonts anymore last version with fonts is v4

Comment: What does "building route" mean in this context? Is there any other way to create a web font from the collection of svg files?

Answer (score 12):

Why don't we just use cdn link, or download from there?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Primer/3.0.1/css/primer.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/octicons/3.5.0/octicons.min.css">
```

Comment: This answer seems deprecated, no? It seems Octicons changed in the way of how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Bower](http://bower.io) to install Octicons.

bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    ...
    "dependencies": {   
        "octicons": "4.3.0",
    }
}
```

Then link to wherever your bower libraries are being held:

```
<link href="/libs/octicons/build/font/octicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This worked for me. The Octicons package available on the website as of 2019 is missing the fonts, but the one in bower has all the necessary files.

Answer (score 1):

Update for those reading in 2023:

I faced a similar issue and was annoyed by how, in spite of using Bootstrap icons and Devicon as CDN-distributed CSS, I had to resort to importing Octicon SVGs individually. For this reason, I created my own little build pipeline that bundles the SVGs in a CSS distribution. Here is the [project repository](https://github.com/dabico/octicons-css), and if you want to include it using CDN:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/octicons-css/octicons.min.css">
```